Issues trying to load saved Keras U-Net model from h5 file
I've been assigned a task in my company to try to hydrate a model that was trained for a previous project, and while I can load it again, I'm failing to try it and I don't know why.
The model follows a U-Net architecture, and here's the output of the summary() method after calling load_weights().
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 640, 512, 1  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)                (None, 640, 512, 64  640         ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)              (None, 640, 512, 64  36928       ['conv2d[0][0]']                 
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 320, 256, 64  0           ['conv2d_1[0][0]']               
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)              (None, 320, 256, 12  73856       ['max_pooling2d[0][0]']          
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)              (None, 320, 256, 12  147584      ['conv2d_2[0][0]']               
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 160, 128, 12  0          ['conv2d_3[0][0]']               
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)              (None, 160, 128, 25  295168      ['max_pooling2d_1[0][0]']        
                                6)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)              (None, 160, 128, 25  590080      ['conv2d_4[0][0]']               
                                6)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 80, 64, 256)  0          ['conv2d_5[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 64, 512)  1180160     ['max_pooling2d_2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)              (None, 80, 64, 512)  2359808     ['conv2d_6[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 40, 32, 512)  0          ['conv2d_7[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)              (None, 40, 32, 1024  4719616     ['max_pooling2d_3[0][0]']        
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)              (None, 40, 32, 1024  9438208     ['conv2d_8[0][0]']               
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D)   (None, 80, 64, 1024  0           ['conv2d_9[0][0]']               
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 80, 64, 1536  0           ['up_sampling2d[0][0]',          
                                )                                 'conv2d_7[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)             (None, 80, 64, 512)  7078400     ['concatenate[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_11 (Conv2D)             (None, 80, 64, 512)  2359808     ['conv2d_10[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 160, 128, 51  0          ['conv2d_11[0][0]']              
                                2)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_1 (Concatenate)    (None, 160, 128, 76  0           ['up_sampling2d_1[0][0]',        
                                8)                                'conv2d_5[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_12 (Conv2D)             (None, 160, 128, 25  1769728     ['concatenate_1[0][0]']          
                                6)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_13 (Conv2D)             (None, 160, 128, 25  590080      ['conv2d_12[0][0]']              
                                6)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 320, 256, 25  0          ['conv2d_13[0][0]']              
                                6)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_2 (Concatenate)    (None, 320, 256, 38  0           ['up_sampling2d_2[0][0]',        
                                4)                                'conv2d_3[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_14 (Conv2D)             (None, 320, 256, 12  442496      ['concatenate_2[0][0]']          
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_15 (Conv2D)             (None, 320, 256, 12  147584      ['conv2d_14[0][0]']              
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 640, 512, 12  0          ['conv2d_15[0][0]']              
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_3 (Concatenate)    (None, 640, 512, 19  0           ['up_sampling2d_3[0][0]',        
                                2)                                'conv2d_1[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_16 (Conv2D)             (None, 640, 512, 64  110656      ['concatenate_3[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_17 (Conv2D)             (None, 640, 512, 64  36928       ['conv2d_16[0][0]']              
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_18 (Conv2D)             (None, 640, 512, 1)  65          ['conv2d_17[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 31,377,793
Trainable params: 31,377,793
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

My main concern is that when I load a picture as an numpy array, ending up with an input shaped (640, 512, 1), just like the first layer, I get the following error.
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

img_size = (640,512)
color_mode = "grayscale" 
image = img_to_array(load_img(image_path, target_size=self.image_size, color_mode=self.color_mode))
image = image/255.0
print(image.shape)
#(640, 512, 1)

#unet is a wrapper class which contains the model described above
#unet.load_weights('../../models/unet_model_i_04.h5')
unet.model.predict(image)

This snippet produces this error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 640, 512, 1), found shape=(32, 512, 1)

I tried changing the shape of the input, and hence the image size, (I suspect, based on an outdated notebook I was granted access to, that when the model was initially trained and exported, it was done using 320x256 images, but that only changes the error to
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 320, 256, 1), found shape=(32, 256, 1)


What does it mean to "hydrate" a model?

model.predict() expects batches of input. I'm not sure why you get a 32 in your image shape in the error, but you could try to expand the first dimension to get from (640, 512, 1) to (1, 640, 512, 1). You can do that with numpy.expand_dims or tf.expand_dims.

@Dr.Snoopy to load it from a saved file to avoid having to train it again, maybe I should have used "load"

@mhenning okay let me try, thanks

You should edit the question and replace the strange words (hydrate) with the  correct words, so people can find the question in the future.

@Dr.Snoopy thanks for the suggestion

@mhenning thanks for your comment, it worked! I had an old snippet where they used predict with a straight image (instead of a batch with a single image), so I didn't even try to change that. Thanks again!

As someone suggested in the comments, try expanding the dimension of the input tensor. The model expect a batch of images as input, and for one image, the input shape should be 1 x H x W x 1:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

img_size = (640,512)
color_mode = "grayscale" 
image = img_to_array(load_img(image_path, target_size=imge_size, color_mode=color_mode))
image = image/255.0
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
print(image.shape)
#(1, 640, 512, 1)

#unet is a wrapper class which contains the model described above
#unet.load_weights('../../models/unet_model_i_04.h5')
unet.model.predict(image)


Thanks for your example, I'll mark your answer as the one even if @mhenning said it first.
